# Getting twitter friends not working using linq-to-twitter

Tags: twitter, linq-to-twitter

I'm trying to use new linq2twitter version (4.1.0) but i just can't get it work.
I used to work with version 2.1.11 until now and it worked just fine.

i've opened a new asp.net project and this is my code

Can you tell me what i am doing wrong?
The "DoSingleUserAuth" works fine. i enter the right tokens...

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task demoTask = DoDemosAsync();
        demoTask.Wait();
    }

    static async Task DoDemosAsync()
    {
        var auth = DoSingleUserAuth();

        var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);

        await ShowFriendsAsync(twitterCtx);
    }

    static IAuthorizer DoSingleUserAuth()
    {
        var auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer
        {
            CredentialStore = new SingleUserInMemoryCredentialStore
            {
                ConsumerKey = "ConsumerKey",
                ConsumerSecret = "ConsumerSecret",
                AccessToken = "AccessToken",
                AccessTokenSecret = "AccessTokenSecret"
            }
        };

        return auth;
    }

    static async Task ShowFriendsAsync(TwitterContext twitterCtx)
    {
        var friendship =
            await
            (from friend in twitterCtx.Friendship
             where friend.Type == FriendshipType.Show &&
                   friend.SourceScreenName == "Linq2Twitr" &&
                   friend.TargetScreenName == "JoeMayo"
             select friend)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

        if (friendship != null &&
            friendship.SourceRelationship != null &&
            friendship.TargetRelationship != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                    "\nJoeMayo follows LinqToTweeter: " +
                    friendship.SourceRelationship.FollowedBy +
                    "\nLinqToTweeter follows JoeMayo: " +
                    friendship.TargetRelationship.FollowedBy);
        }
    }
```

10x,
Lior

Comment: Someone down voted this question and that doesn't make sense. The question seems fine to me. The Console.WriteLine in ShowFriendsAsync is probably out of the Console samples, but I don't see that as a big deal since I loaded the code and it compiled an ran. This was a short sample that illustrated the problem perfectly, especially if you look at my answer at how to fix it. I wish people would be a little nicer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do to fix this, make your page async and replace Wait with await:

Add the Async="true" attribute to your @Page directive:

```
    <%@ Page Async="true" ... %>
```

You can rewrite Page_Load by making it async and awaiting DoDemosAsync like this:

```
    protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await DoDemosAsync();
    }
```

The problem was that calling Wait() caused a deadlock. With async, you should make your calls async all the way through the call chain.

Answer (score 0):

i can see that 
var result = Task.Run(() => ShowFriendsAsync(twitterCtx)).Result;

works fine for me. is this a good approach?

Lior